# Name der stilistischen Figur »ruhe sanfte, sanfte ruh!«

Tags: style

Im Schlusschor der Matthäus-Passion hat Johann Sebastian Bach unter anderem diesen Text vertont:

> Wir setzen uns mit Tränen nieder
>   Und rufen dir im Grabe zu:
>   **Ruhe sanfte, sanfte ruh!**

In modernem Alltags-Deutsch würde man das Adverb nicht deklinieren, und das e am Ende des zweiten Verbs würde man entweder stehen lassen, oder sein Fehlen durch ein Auslassungszeichen markieren. Der fragliche Teil lautete dann:

> Ruhe sanft, sanft ruh'!

Mir wurde gesagt, dass diese stilistische Besonderheit, bei der zwei Wörter in umgekehrter Reihenfolge wiederholt werden, einen eigenen Namen hätte. Ich habe ihn aber leider vergessen und hoffe, dass mir hier jemand diese Bezeichnung nennen kann.

Zudem wüsste ich gerne, ob dieses Stilmittel nur bei *Verb Adverb, Adverb Verb* Anwendung findet, oder ob das auch bei anderen Wortarten eingesetzt wird, und ob es eine Rolle spielt, dass diese Phrase einen Imperativ darstellt.

Comment: Inwieweit ist der Mittelteil, wie es im Alltagsdeutsch wäre, relevant für die Fragen?

Comment: Es handelt sich um eine spezielle Art des [Chiasmus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus). Ob dieser Chiasmus in deinem Falle einen eigenen Namen hat, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: Um eine [Antimetabole](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole) handelt es sich auch nicht wirklich (fehlende Antithese); das kommt der Sache aber ein Stück näher.

Comment: @Emanuel: Um klarzustellen, dass es eben nicht darum geht.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich habe keine Ahnung, ob das relevant ist. Vielleicht gibt es diese Wendung heute auch noch, vielleicht aber eben nicht. Ich habe gehofft, dass das jemand vielleicht in der Antwort thematisieren könnte.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Nein, es ging mir nicht darum zu zeigen, dass es nicht darum geht. Ich habe schlichtweg keine Ahnung, ob das auch für Alltagsdeutsch relevant sein könnte. (Ich vermute, dass das im normalen Sprachgebrauch nicht vorkommt, habe darüber aber keine Gewissheit)

Comment: Ich hab' gefragt, da ich beim Lesen zunächst den Eindruck gekriegt habe, du willst auf die Grammatik hinaus, insbesondere das flektierte Adverb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das ist ein Spezialfall eines [Chiasmus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus), bei dem nicht nur die Art der überkreuzten Wörter gleich ist, sondern die Wörter selbst. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanodos) und auch [diese Stilmittelliste](http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/fakultaeten/fakultaet_sprach_literatur_und_kulturwissenschaften/germanistik/ndl_didaktik/uebersicht/lehre/lehre_feilhaber/Rhethorische%20Figuren%20und%20Stilmittel.pdf) nennen das *Epanodos,* wobei im vorliegenden Fall allerdings noch besonders ist, dass keine weiteren Wörter dazwischen geschoben sind.

Answer (score 6):

In *Duden – Das Fremdwörterbuch* und in *Duden – Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* findet man:

> **Epanodos**, die; –, …doi [griech. epánodos = Rückkehr] (Rhet., Stilk.): *Wiederholung eines Satzes, aber in umgekehrter Wortfolge* (z. B. Ich preise den Herrn, den Herrn preise ich).